# Algorithm equalivence from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I've plotted a 3-d mesh in `Matlab` by below little `m-file`:

```
[x,n] = meshgrid(0:0.1:20, 1:1:100);

mu = 0;
sigma = sqrt(2)./n;

f = normcdf(x,mu,sigma);

mesh(x,n,f);
```

I am going to acquire the same result by utilization of `Python` and its corresponding modules, by below code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 1

def integrand(x, n):
    return (n/(2*sigma*np.sqrt(np.pi)))*np.exp(-(n**2*x**2)/(4*sigma**2))

tt = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
nn = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)  

T = np.zeros([len(tt), len(nn)])

for i,t in enumerate(tt):
    for j,n in enumerate(nn):
        T[i, j], _ = quad(integrand, -np.inf, t, args=(n,))

x, y = np.mgrid[0:20:0.01, 1:101:1]

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, T)

plt.show()
```

But the output of the `Python` is is considerably different with the `Matlab` one, and as a matter of fact is unacceptable.
I am afraid of wrong utilization of the functions just like `linespace`, `enumerate` or `mgrid`...

Does somebody have any idea about?!...

PS. Unfortunately, I couldn't insert the output plots within this thread...!

Best

..............................

Edit: I changed the `linespace` and `mgrid` intervals and replaced `plot_surface` method... The output is 3d now with the suitable accuracy and smoothness...

Comment: `tt = np.linspace(0, 19, 20)` looks like it should be 201 instead of 19?

Comment: I've updated the question, based on your advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see the equivalent solution would be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

x, n = np.mgrid[0:20:0.01, 1:100:1]

mu = 0
sigma = np.sqrt(2)/n

f = norm.cdf(x, mu, sigma)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, n, f, rstride=x.shape[0]//20, cstride=x.shape[1]//20, alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately 3D plotting with matplotlib is not as straight forward as with matlab.

Here is the plot from this code:
[image: matplotlib result of my code]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution... But there are two issues:
1- The result is different with my solution and the matlab-driven code.. How would you assess that?
2- I didn't understand that how did you legally replaced `sigma` with `np.sqrt(2)*n`, as it should be 1... Could you please give some comment upon?

Comment: @Ordenador well if you ignore the figure I posted and use the code I provide as it is, it is producing exaclty the same as your matlab script, which says `sigma = sqrt(2)./n` ;)  
However your python script is integrating over `norm(t*n,0,1)` for t=0 to x which is the same as `normcdf(x,0,n)`. Therefore the sigma in your python script actually is `n` and not `1`, therefore your scripts do not agree on the value of sigma and I had no Idea what you actually need. I chose `sigma = np.sqrt(2)*n` for my plot because for some reason I thought it is a good compromise...

Comment: Sorry, just realized I mixed something up... integral over `norm(t*n,0,1)` for t=0 to x is equivalent to `normcdf(t,0,1/n)`, which looks similar to `normcdf(t,0,sqrt(2)/n)` which is why your script *looks* like it is producing the same figure but technically it is not. I updated the figure to be what my code produces.

Answer (score 1):

Your Matlab code generate 201 points through x:

```
[x,n] = meshgrid(0:0.1:20, 1:1:100);
```

While your Python code generate only 20 points:

```
tt = np.linspace(0, 19, 20)
```

Maybe it's causing accuracy problems?
Try this code:

```
tt = np.linspace(0, 20, 201)
```

Answer (score 0):

The seminal points to resolve the problem was:

1- Necessity of the equivalence regarding the provided dimensions of the `linespace` and `mgrid` functions...

2- Utilization of a mesh with more density to make a bee line into a high degree of smoothness...

3- Application of a 3d plotter function, like `plot_surf`...

The current code is totally valid...